# Debian 8 GitWeb page shows source-code

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, git

Recently I have started to set-up my own WebServer after buying a domain and planning to host my portfolio on it. But before that I needed a way to display anything at all on my domain, so first thing I did was putting a Debian droplet on the poor thing and set-up LAMP. So far so good, now for the project I'm working on with multiple people I want to pull from a git repository I host on the server and only I can push to. So that updates are controlled and always distributed "on-time". Now here's my problem:

I managed to get git (git-daemon) working on my localhost, but if I try to connect to it via my domain name it doesn't recognize my connection. As such I've tried for a few hours now to find some good tutorials. And when I thought I'd finally done it [this](http://git.%3Cremoved%3E.nl/) happened. And frankly, I don't even know what to do. I followed [this](http://dereenigne.org/debian/debian-gitweb-server) guy's tutorial and after fixing the few restart errors (because of a simple syntax change over time) it worked on localhost. But not on the domain and not via a Git client which retrieves form a git:// url.

Comment: The script being served as a normal file is a symptom of the `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi` not being in effect. It would help if you could show your actual apache config. It's possible you have some of the directives in the wrong VirtualHost or Directory. Also: you used the apache-2.2 tag but your server headers say `Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)`

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. First things first: No need for formalities, addressing your audience, or thanks. This is a Q&A forum. I took care of editing that out. Second: This fits better on SuperUser.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I changed the tag, my apologies. This is what is currently in my git.brentdijsselbloem.nl.conf: https://gyazo.com/e1a8689ffb9f2246b089870e8272c2bd
               |
DavidMakogon Thank you for the warm welcome. Do you want me to move/repost this on SuperUser?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley This is the conf for /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: http://pastebin.com/r9dbbSTz

Comment: That's not the one with the CGI enabling stuff

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley then what would you like to see? I thought this is what you meant.

Comment: In the tutorial you linked to, the file is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/git.dereenigne.org`. If you followed that tutorial, you must have some equivalent of that file.

Comment: Correct, @WumpusQ.Wumbley That is the gyazo of the conf a few comments back. https://gyazo.com/e1a8689ffb9f2246b089870e8272c2bd

Comment: Sorry, I missed that one and only noticed the second link. So CGI is enabled there. I'd suspect the module isn't loaded, but if it's working on localhost that can't be it. Have you checked the `error.log`?

Comment: I have. There is nothing erroring connected to the CGI there, though. The git://localhost/project.git works, but if you change that to a domain-name it doesn't. https://gyazo.com/4bc8367207f5c4bac9eb1fcd6d3e5a09

Comment: https://gyazo.com/113269eb72c0df5e6f6853c7fe24663a As you can see, @WumpusQ.Wumbley , here I do it with the localhost and it works. But change it to my domain name and you get the above result.

Comment: wait a minute... `git://localhost` doesn't prove anything. You need to use `http://localhost` to have a valid comparison. I've been assuming that the link you gave, `http://dereenigne.org/debian/debian-gitweb-server` is the thing we're trying to debug. If `git://` is where you're really having a problem, then apache has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Apologies, I jumbled 2 different things together. my website: http://git.brentdijsselbloem.nl/ should look the same as http://git.dereenigne.org/ but without the repositories he has and with the standard layout. But it's just printing source code. The git:// is indeed another problem of itself. Sorry.

Comment: I found this: http://blog.gauner.org/2010/02/setting-up-gitweb-on-debian/ And that has helped me to fix the issue I had. But I'm now at a 403 Forbidden... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by executing

```
root@server:~# a2enmod cgi
Enabling module cgi.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart
root@server:~# service apache2 restart
```

I feel like such a dumbass. xD

Thanks for all the help.